# Why does my Netgear WNR 1000 router keep giving the wrong IP address?

Tags: router, internet, ip, home-networking

For a while my Internet has stopped working. My house has two routers, one for the WiFi which is a Belkin and the other for routing wired connections for home entertainment systems which is a Netgear.

When I did a traceroute to my modem, I noticed my Netgear WNR 1000 router got the IP address of 192.168.1.2 instead of 192.168.1.1. I can still access its settings using 192.168.1.1 address. Whenever that Netgear router tries to send a hop there is a `!H` symbol instead.

I've tried unplugging the modem and all the routers and plugging them back in. I have also tried doing `ipconfig /release` and `/renew`. When I removed the Netgear router at the expense of the home entertainment systems, the Internet started working again.

How do I got my Netgear to stop having the wrong IP address so I can have my home entertainment system back again?

Comment: Can you clarify how your network is set up? How are the routers connected to your modem and computers and what addresses are associated with which interfaces?

Comment: My wifi is connected from the belkin which has an ip of 192.168.2.1 which connects from the wall to a Netgear router in my basement (ip 192.168.1.1) which connects to the modem (192.168.1.100) and also connects to all  the wall units leading to my home entertainment. The Netgear is whats causing the trouble since it keeps getting a false ip of 192.168.1.2 in traceroute and is preventing the wifi router from connecting to the modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your ISP modem may not be in bridge mode, and may be using the 192.168.1.1 address you want your netgear to have.  Disconnect your netgear from your network and plug into your ISP modem, what IP do you get?  What IP is the modem?  If possible put your ISP modem in [bridge mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_%28networking%29#Transparent_bridging).  This will pass all traffic from your ISP modem straight to your netgear, it will also make the ISP modem "disappear from your network, it will no longer have a LAN address.  Once you have this set up, your wireless AP can be plugged into your Netgear and accessed as you current have it set up.  It sounds like you have some complex networking as your wireless is on a different network then your lan, but it may have been a typo.  In the end I would expect it to look like this.
ISP Modem: Transpent in Bridge Mode
Netgear: 192.168.1.1
Belkin: 192.138.1.2

In short I think your ISP modem is taking the LAN address your want your Netgear to have.